# How can I Show a text box together with a log-log plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I would like to show a log-log plot together with a text box.

I tried
`Show[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}], Graphics[Text["My text", {.5, .5}]]]`,
but I don't see the text box anywhere:

[image]

`LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Text["My text", {.5, .5}]}]` doesn't work either.

How can I get my text box to appear? Is the `LogLogPlot` doing something weird to Mathematica's internal coordinate system?

Comment: Or used scaled coordinates, e.g., `Show[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
 Graphics[Text["My text", Scaled[{.45, .55}]]]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I am not sure why you would choose this way of entering text, you can use [**`Overlay`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html?v=13.2)

```
p1 = LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}];
p2 = Graphics[Text["My text", {.5, .5}]];
Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

> [image: overlay]

**Edit:** since you are using `LogLog` you need to specify that in the text position

```
LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["Hello", {Log[0.2], Log[0.1]}]}]
```

> [image: plot]

And of course,

```
p1 = LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}];
p2 = Graphics[Text["My text", {Log[0.2], Log[0.1]}]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

> [image: show]

[**`Show`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) vs [**`Overlay`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html)

> [image: show1]

> [image: overlay1]

Comment: Why does `Overlay` work when `Show` and `Epilog` don't? Also, what's a better way to enter text?

Comment: @tparker see the edit. The links for the docs are included and a brief explanation.